# Density of squared random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

$X \sim Unif(a, b)$, $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary numbers.

I need to calculate the density of $Y = X^2$. I know about Method of transformations. But in my case the function is not invertible on $R$. However, the function is invertible on the positive and negative half-axes. Is there any way to apply this here?

I also tried to calculate directly through the distribution function. But with any $a$ and $b$ this is difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the the equivalent events.

If $a,b>0$ or $a,b<0$, then
$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2|b-a|\sqrt{y}}, & a^2<y<b^2\\
0, & \text{o.w.}
\end{cases}$.

If $a<0$ and $b>0$, let $m=\min\{|a|,|b|\}$, and $M=\max\{|a|,|b|\}$, then

$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(M+m)\sqrt{y}}, & 0<y<m^2\\
\frac{1}{2(M+m)\sqrt{y}}, & m^2<y<M^2\\
0, & \text{o.w.}
\end{cases}$

because $y \in (0,m^2)$ occurs if $x = \pm \sqrt{y}$, but $y\in(m^2, M^2)$ only occurs if $x=\sqrt{y}$, when $M=b$, or if $x=-\sqrt{y}$, when $M=|a|$.

Comment: Thank you. But in the second string I think should be $m^2<y<M^2$. To take into account case $a, b <0$.